# Docker MySQL: Communication link failure

Tags: mysql, spring, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have created a docker container of mysql with the database init. Now i am trying to connect my local spring boot project with that mysql in container. It always give me communication link failure.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/erp
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password = password
```

I also tried changing localhost with the name of container but still nothing works.

**EDIT: 1**

I have clones this [repository](https://github.com/givanthak/spring-boot-rest-api-tutorial) and tried to connect this project with docker mysql. Still the error is same. I believe that I am missing something.

Comment: Can you give more details about the docker-compose file or how you run your mysql container ?

Comment: How are you starting your database container and application container? Are you using docker-compose? Most probably the issue is usage of `localhost` in `spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/erp`

Comment: @MickaelB. I don't have docker-compose file. After creating container I use this command to run the container `docker start d8(id of my container)`

Comment: Maybe they are not in the same network, if you try to run both container with `--network="host"` and expose the port of your database it could work

Comment: I have not created any the container of spring project. I just have the empty container of mysql with database in it. Now I am trying to run my project locally and accessing the DB of docker container mysql

Comment: @ShashankV I also have a feeling that issue is in datasource.url

Comment: Have you exposed port 3306 so that it's accessible outside containers? See `ports` property in Docker Compose specification.

Comment: @Marcin I dont have docker-compose file.

Comment: are you able to find your container running using docker ps ? and able to access the data using docker exec -it container_id bash.

Comment: Yeah my container is up and I can see database in it using `docker exec -it 24647 bash`

Comment: Try getting the ip of container using docker inspect container_id | grep "IPAddress" and then map that ip instead of localhost in the url. Each container has it's own ip which is different from localhost.

Comment: Tried that but no luck using `docker inspect`

Comment: You changed the localhost to ip yet it didn't work ? Oh Gosh then what is the issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205509/discussion-between-mukesh-and-ali-wahab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. My container was not accessible outside of docker VM. So I have to use the following flag to `--publish 6603:3306`. Port 6603 is the port of local PC which will connect directly with container port 3306 on which mysql is running.

```
docker run --name mysql-standalone -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -e MYSQL_USER=sa -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password --publish 6603:3306 -d mysql:5.6
```

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:6603/test
```